# Can not retrieve data from Hive after application restart

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Everything works fine until I **restart** the app (close the app and open it) and can not see previously saved data, but if I check the box status it is opened and empty. Am I doing something wrong?

- Running on real device Xiaomi Redmi 4A (actually the problem appears
  also on Iphone devices)
- Working on Mac M1
- Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.2 20D64 darwin-arm,
  locale ru)
- I found "problem" in github [repo](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/620) but    there is nothing useful

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  // init hive
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await lds.init();
  // init app
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

hive init file

```
Future<void> init() async {
  final appDocumentDirectory = await path.getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);

  // registering entities
  Hive.registerAdapter(ItemModelAdapter());
}
```

save and load functions

```
class ItemLocalDataSource {
  static const String BOX_ITEMS = 'item-models';

  Future<List<ItemModel>> getLocalItems() async {
    await Hive.openBox(BOX_ITEMS);
    final box = Hive.box(BOX_ITEMS);
    final items = box.get(0) as List<ItemModel>;
    return items;
  }

  Future<void> setLocalItems(List<ItemModel> items) async {
    await Hive.openBox(BOX_ITEMS);
    final box = Hive.box(BOX_ITEMS);
    box.put(0, items);
    print('saved $items');
  }
}
```

package versions I am using in pubspec.yaml

```
  # hive (local data storage)
  hive: ^1.4.4+1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  # hive adapter generator
  hive_generator: ^0.8.2
  # build runner
  build_runner:
```

Comment: HI have you fixed this problem? I encountered it recently and can't seem to find a fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have upgraded Dart SDK , app have caused the same issue. When I have downgraded the Dart SDK, Hive started working as expected. Solution is downgrading Dart SDK. My current SDK is:

```
Dart SDK version: 2.14.2 (stable)
```

Comment: Hi how do I change the dart sdk version?

Comment: @Dean Villamia I have rolled back my files with github, but don't know what to do to change the dart sdk. You can try to change sdks part in pubspec.lock, which I remember after changing this file it have been worked. `sdks:   dart: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"   flutter: ">=2.5.0` it should be something like that

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me
https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-local-data-persistence-flutter-hive/

For some reason the Model wasn't handling the late keyword I think?
Feel free to correct me in the comments as I would also like to learn :D